# What does a trait requiring Sized have to do with being unable to have trait objects of that trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I have this code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2ff313307dbc9b6af8d280117be970a8)):

```
trait NodeLike: Sized {}

fn main() {
    let s: Box<NodeLike> = panic!();
}
```

Which does not compile:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `NodeLike` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:4:12
  |
4 |     let s: Box<NodeLike> = panic!();
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `NodeLike` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

After all I read, I still don't understand why it does not compile and why it does without the `Sized` constraint.

As far as I know:

- `Box<NodeLike>` is treated as `Box<dyn NodeLike>` which uses dynamic dispatch for method calls.
- `Box<NodeLike>` is sized anyways, regardless of its item type.
- The sized/unsized theory is necessary because there are types whose size is not known upfront (like arrays or strings).
- The `Sized` marker on traits enforces implementing types to be sized.

What does requiring that implementing types are `Sized` have to do with not being able to have objects (with dynamic dispatch) of that trait?

Comment: You should use the `dyn` notation. This is a less ambiguous notation.

Comment: All is explained in [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/error-index.html#the-trait-cannot-require-self-sized).

Comment: The documentation does not explain much.
> We cannot create an object of type Box<Foo> or &Foo since in this case Self would not be Sized.
Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why a function on a trait object cannot be called when bounded with \`Self: Sized\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822118/why-a-function-on-a-trait-object-cannot-be-called-when-bounded-with-self-sized)

Comment: @trentcl that link helped, thanks. So the `Sized` marker is basically just a switch to enable or disable object instances of a given trait?

Comment: As a supertrait, that's one thing it does. But in general `Sized` is just a trait that is satisfied by types with a compile-time-known size. You can use it as a supertrait to disable trait objects of the subtrait, but that's not its primary use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having `Self: ?Sized` on the *trait type itself* is a required property for a trait object, i.e. for 'object safety', even though you can have an `impl` on a `Self: ?Sized` trait with a `Sized` type. Hence confusion.

It's a drawback that was decided upon in [RFC 255](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0255-object-safety.html) which deals with object safety (warning: obsolete Rust syntax).

It's a long read, but one of the alternatives was to determine 'object safety' by only analyzing the methods of the trait. It is admitted in the RFC that having this restriction will make some code that could have worked not to compile. (*"This is a breaking change and forbids some safe code which is legal today."*).

We can go around this if we lower the restriction only to the trait members function that actually need it, e.g. this compiles:

```rust
trait NodeLike {
    fn method_foo(&self) -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
}

fn main() {
    let s: Box<NodeLike> = panic!();
    // Compiles!
}
```

However, we cannot call those `Self: Sized` methods via a trait object, and this is a limitation that is [explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822118/why-a-function-on-a-trait-object-cannot-be-called-when-bounded-with-self-sized). Here, calling `s.method_foo();` will break compilation.

Note that the `Self: Sized` constraint limits compilation even if the method does not make use of `Self` at all and could have been a callable trait object method otherwise.