# Is it possible to store different concrete types implementing the same non-object safe trait in a collection?

Tags: rust

A trait like this prevents `&dyn DoAction` because of the generic function:

```rust
trait DoAction {
    fn action<T: T1 + T2>(&self, s: &T) { 
        s.action_t1();
        s.action_t2();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write a function where the `Vec` contains different concrete types, but they all implement the trait `DoAction`?

```rust
fn run_all(runners: Vec<&impl DoAction>) {}
```

The main issue I want to solve is being able to loop over these different concrete types - but I cannot use `Vec<&dyn T>` trait objects as decribed in [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423) because of the generic trait function.

For example:

```rust
struct SA {
    sa: u32,
}

struct SB {
    sb: u32,
}

trait T1 {
    fn action_t1(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

trait T2 {
    fn action_t2(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

impl T1 for SA {}
impl T1 for SB {}
impl T2 for SA {}
impl T2 for SB {}

impl T1 for &SA {}
impl T1 for &SB {}
impl T2 for &SA {}
impl T2 for &SB {}

trait DoAction {
    fn action<T: T1 + T2>(&self, s: &T) {
        s.action_t1();
        s.action_t2();
    }
}

struct Runner1 {}
impl DoAction for Runner1 {}

struct Runner2 {}
impl DoAction for Runner2 {}

fn run_all(runners: Vec<&impl DoAction>, s: (impl T1 + T2)) {
    for r in runners {
        r.action(&s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = SA { sa: 123 };

    let r1 = Runner1 {};
    let r2 = Runner2 {};

    let ls = vec![&r1, &r2];
    run_all(ls, &a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d51fe637a4775a5c1aff825a669f0b73)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a generic method inside a trait require trait object to be sized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620022/why-does-a-generic-method-inside-a-trait-require-trait-object-to-be-sized)

Comment: Partially yes, I understand the generic requires a concrete type. But Im not sure of the possible options for looping over different concrete types having the same trait - so it's impossible to do?

Answer (score 4):

Since such a function would only work for some concrete type, you can work around this by making a trait that "concretizes" the method and implement it for all types implementing `DoAction`:

```rust
trait DoConcreteAction<T> {
    fn concrete_action(&self, s: &T);
}

impl<T, U> DoConcreteAction<U> for T
where
    T: DoAction,
    U: T1 + T2,
{
    fn concrete_action(&self, s: &U) {
        self.action(s)
    }
}

fn run_all<T>(runners: Vec<&dyn DoConcreteAction<T>>, s: &T) {
    for r in runners {
        r.concrete_action(&s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = SA { sa: 123 };

    let r1 = Runner1 {};
    let r2 = Runner2 {};

    let ls: Vec<&dyn DoConcreteAction<SA>> = vec![&r1, &r2];
    run_all(ls, &a);
}
```

[Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39ab31e4ad015419d49c035590cbb14f)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to keep the `impl T1 + T2` as the second arg to `run_all`? So I would roughly have a `(Vec<DoAction>, Vec<T1+T2>)`, and then pass every `T1+T2` to every `DoAction.action(x)`. I think the solution works because SA is passed to the generic `DoConcreteAction` making it concrete, but this also removes the `impl T1+T2` trait bound on `run_all`. Im thinking maybe I should just use an enum here instead of generics.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a super trait that is automatically implemented for any type that implements `T1` and `T2`:

```rust
trait T1AndT2: T1 + T2 {}

impl<T: T1 + T2> T1AndT2 for T {}
```

And then change `DoAction` to accept a trait object (`T1AndT2`) instead of generics:

```rust
trait DoAction {
    fn action(&self, s: &dyn T1AndT2) { 
        s.action_t1();
        s.action_t2();
    }
}
```

Now that `DoAction` does not use generics, you can create a vector of `DoAction` objects:

```rust
let ls: Vec::<&dyn DoAction> = vec![&r1, &r2];
```

And use it in your function:

```rust
run_all(ls);
```

[Runnable Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4aeb8a62e97baddd836a73102a6c04a5)

Comment: This works with the example code, but with my code base the `DoAction` `action` function will have different implementations for each struct (not just the default), and each implementation will take a subset of the traits from `DoAction` `action` (for example, the generic function on the struct may be `fn action<T: T1>` (notice it does not include T2). In my code base I have T1 to T5